# Determine amount of congruent numbers

Tags: modular-arithmetic, cryptography

I found the claim in a paper that there are at max 8 integers mod $2^{130}-5$ congruent to one integer mod $2^{128}$.
$$u \pmod {2^{130}-5} \equiv g  \pmod {2^{128}} \quad\text{ with }u \in U \quad \#U \le 8 $$
So $2^{130}-5$ is almost 4 times larger than $2^{128}$ and therefore $g , g + 2^{128}, g +2^{129}$ should be congruent integers to g. What are the other 5 integers?

Comment: It's not clear what it means for $a\mod M \equiv b\mod N$. Don't you just mean that they are equal?

Comment: Can you give a citation for, or a link to, this paper?

Comment: @GerryMyerson [PDF](http://cr.yp.to/mac/poly1305-20050329.pdf) the claim is on top of page 9

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I'm pretty sure they are just congruent and not equal. There can be multiple numbers a that are congruent to b.

Comment: Congruence is modulo one number, not modulo two different numbers.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Ok. Thanks for clarifying that.

Comment: As an aside, do note that anything that is "always less than 5" is, indeed, always "at most 8". And the phrase "at max 8" can be interpreted as meaning "at most 8", rather than "the maximum value is 8".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not what the paper says!  The paper refers to integers in the interval $[-2^{130}+6, 2^{130}-6]$, not integers modulo $2^{130}-5$.  There are about twice as many of the former than the latter.  You're missing all the negative values.

Comment: Uh darn, I somehow misunderstood that part. And the negative values are $2^{128} - g, 2^{129} -g, 3 * 2^{128} - g$, right? Then I'm still missing one.

Comment: @SaschaSchmidt $g-2^{128}, g-2\cdot2^{128}, g-3\cdot2^{128},g-4\cdot2^{128}$.  The numbers you list are not generally negative, nor congruent to $g$.

Comment: I'm glad I asked OP to give the link to the paper.

Answer (score 0):

A fourth one (not always available) is $g+3\cdot 2^{128}$  I don't know where the other four come from.